# Как запустить QEMU aarch64?

Tags: android, linux, termux, qemu

Моя цель - запустить Linux на aarch64. Есть debian-11.2.0-netinstall.iso, есть vmlinuz-debian12, есть initrd-debian12.gz. Пробую:

```
$ qemu-system-aarch64 -machine virt,gic-version=3 -machine virtualization=true -cpu max -smp cpus=2 -m 512M -k en-gb -pflash efi.img -pflash varstore.img -net user -drive if=none,id=cd,file=debian-11.2.0-arm64-netinst.iso -device virtio-blk-device,drive=cd -boot menu=on
$ qemu-system-aarch64 -machine virt -machine virtualization=true -cpu max -smp cpus=2 -m 512M -k en-gb -drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=efi.img,readonly -drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=varstore.img -device virtio-scsi-pci,id=scsi0 -object rng-random,filename=/dev/urandom,id=rng0 -device virtio-rng-pci,rng=rng0 -net user -drive if=none,id=cd,file=debian-11.2.0-arm64-netinst.iso -device scsi-cd,drive=cd -boot menu=on
$ qemu-system-aarch64 -machine virt -machine virtualization=true -cpu max -smp cpus=2 -m 512M -k en-gb -drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=efi.img,readonly -drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=varstore.img -device virtio-scsi-pci,id=scsi0 -object rng-random,filename=/dev/urandom,id=rng0 -device virtio-rng-pci,rng=rng0 -net user -boot menu=on -kernel vmlinuz-debian-12 -initrd initrd_debian12.gz
$ qemu-system-aarch64 -machine virt,gic-version=3 -machine virtualization=true -cpu max -smp cpus=2 -m 512M -k en-gb -pflash efi.img -pflash varstore.img -net user -boot menu=on,splash_time=10000,splash=/sdcard/image.png -kernel vmlinuz-debian-12 -initrd initrd_debian12.gz
```

Но ни одна команда не работает. Добавлял и `-append "root=/dev/hd0"`  - не спасает. pflash я делал так:

```
$ truncate -s 64m varstore.img
$ truncate -s 64m efi.img
$ dd if=./aarch64-UEFI.fd of=./efi.img conv=notrunc
```

Что делать? Мне главное - либо вообще установить Debian, либо запустить ядро+initrd. Но дело у меня не доходит даже до запуска UEFI! Что делать?

Comment: qemu-system-aarch64 -M virt  -M virt -m 4G -cpu cortex-a72 -smp 8,sockets=2,cores=4,threads=1 -kernel ./Image -initrd ./initramfs-linux.img -drive file=arm64disk.img,format=raw,index=0,media=disk -no-reboot  -append "root=/dev/vda2 rw console=ttyAMA0"  -netdev user,id=user.0 -device e1000,netdev=user.0

Comment: мое ядро - **vmlinuz**, initrd - **initrd.gz**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я частично разобрался со своей проблемой. Команда: `qemu-system-aarch64 -M virt -cpu cortex-a53 -m 3G -k en-gb -hda system.img -smp cpus=4 -kernel vmlinuz -initrd initrd.gz -append "init=/bin/ash" -nographic -net user`. Работает только с `-nographic` и летит строго в ramdisk, отказывается монтировать диск: возможно, нету дров на ext4.